# symfony 2 form validation (without errors)

Tags: php, forms, entity-framework, validation, symfony

I'm little confuse by this problem :
I got 2 Entity, Horaire (Horaire mean Schedule) and HoraireLine where $horaire->lines is an array of HoraireLine and $horaireLine->horaire is the Horaire owner.

For persist my Horaire's entities i use a collection of HoraireLine's form in Horaire's form, but that last one isValid() return false any way and i didn't got once error. I checked errors in the form, and childs form : none. I check entities' error with :

`$validator = $this->get('validator');
        $errorList = $validator->validate($this->getSeller()->getHoraire()->getLines());`
And an empty array is return. But the form->isValid() is still to false.
I didn't set particulars validator.

Here my code (in my controller) :

```
[...]
    /*
     *  Horaire's form (about horaireLines)
     */

        /*
         *  Init Horaire's lines threatment
         *  (for don't get null horaire line)
         *  @Unlegit indent
         */

        if($this->getSeller()->getHoraire()->getLines()){
            foreach (EnumDay::getEnum() as $k => $day) {
                $this->getSeller()->getHoraire()->addLine(new HoraireLine( $this->getSeller()->getHoraire(), $day, null, null, null, null ));
            }
        }

    $horaireForm = $this->createForm(new HoraireType(), $this->getSeller()->getHoraire());

    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $errorList = $validator->validate($this->getSeller()->getHoraire()->getLines());
    var_dump($errorList);

    if ($horaireForm->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($this->getSeller()->getHoraire());
        /*foreach ($this->getSeller()->getHoraire()->getLines() as $key => $value) {
            $em->persist($value);
        }*/
    }
[...]
```

$this->getSeller() is a shortcut to an object own by the current User, get by the security context.

And here the yaml of entities :

```
Ctx\BaoBundle\Entity\HoraireLine:
type: entity
table: null
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    am_opening:
        type: time
        nullable: true
    am_closing:
        type: time
        nullable: true
    pm_opening:
        type: time
        nullable: true
    pm_closing:
        type: time
        nullable: true
    day:
        type: object
manyToOne:
    horaire:
        targetEntity: Horaire
        inversedBy: lines
        cascade: ["persist", "merge"]
        joinColumn:
            name: horaire_id
            referencedColumnName: id
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }

Ctx\BaoBundle\Entity\Horaire:
type: entity
table: null
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
oneToOne:
    seller:
        targetEntity: Seller
        inversedBy: horaire
        joinColumn:
            name: seller_id
            referencedColumnName: id
        cascade: ["persist", "merge"]
oneToMany:
    lines:
        targetEntity: HoraireLine
        mappedBy: horaire
        cascade: ["persist", "merge"]
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

I use cascade: ["persist", "merge"] because I needed to use the persist cascade, but I don't know if merge is usefull.
I use doctrine for persist entity.

Thank you per advance for answering, and sorry if it's a dummy error x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the error and yes it was a dummy error.

I post for next guys in the same situation :

I just forget to do the $horaireForm->handle($request) after it

```
$horaireForm = $this->createForm(new HoraireType(), $this->getSeller()->getHoraire());
```

Don't forget to init $request by this :

```
public function <name your action>Action(Request $request)
{
```

Symfony will set by himself $request for handle your forms.